# Saving the document id at the time of creating a document in Firebase v9 using React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Hello I want that when creating a new document, where it says "projectId" the id of the document that is automatically generated is passed to the "projectId" field, is this is possible?

[image]

This is my code:

```
addDoc(collection(db, "projects"), {
        name: project,
        uid: currentUser,
        projectId: 'here the proyectId that i dont know how to pass it'
        
        
      })
```

Im using Firebase v9 Modular, Firestore and React JS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will do the trick:

```
import { collection, doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore"; 

// Add a new document with a generated id
const newDocRef = doc(collection(db, "projects"));

// Set the doc, using the id property of the DocumentReference
await setDoc(newDocRef, {
    name: project,
    uid: currentUser,
    projectId: newDocRef.id
  }
);
```

Comment: Thx ! was looking for that for some time 